# How to add my team members to Azure for them to access my subscription

Tags: azure

I'd like to add my team members to my Azure account so that they can access the SQL server, Cloud and VM's for them to configure without using my id.

Answer (score 2):

Through the Portal: Go to Settings -> Administrators -> Add. They will be co-admins with permissions to do pretty much anything.

Comment: Dear BNLF, thank you. Got it done. Was missing a step in Azure Active directory.